# How to get total count of hash-field pairs in redis

Tags: redis

I have `n` number of hashes in a Redis DB. I am interested in knowing how many hash-field pairs exist in total in my db.

I see I can get the number of keys (hashes) in db through `INFO` command. And get number of fields in a given hash by `HLEN`. But neither meets my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also face this situation and  had a long search on this  but I didn't get any direct commands to achieve this.So I use bash script to get the number of keys with respect to their type.

```
REDIS_KEY_PATTERN="${REDIS_KEY_PATTERN:-*}"
for key in $(redis-cli --scan --pattern "$REDIS_KEY_PATTERN")
do
type=$(redis-cli type $key)
if [ $type = "hash" ]
then
    let "count++"
fi
done
echo $count
```

I hope this will be helpful

Comment: True - there is no "built-in" way to do that in Redis and a script, such as the above, is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. I edited @Praga_t script, so we can count all hash fields in database.

```
for key in $(redis-cli --scan); do

    if [ $(redis-cli type $key) = "hash" ]; then
        length=$(redis-cli HLEN $key)

        let "count = count + length"
        echo key=$key, fields=$length. totalCount=$count
    fi 
done
```